# Converting long numbers to hex with sed

Tags: sed

I'm trying to make a `sed` command so that numbers longer than 3 digits were converted to hex. I.e. a string like `124 3275 7535` should result in `124 0xccb 0x1d6f`. Here's what I currently have:

```
sed 's@\([0-9]\{4,\}\)@sh -c "printf 0x%x \1"@ge'
```

But when the string doesn't match, it attempts to run the unchanged string as an external command, so for the example string above I get

> sh: 1: 124: not found

How can I achieve what I'm trying to do (preferably still using `sed`)?

Comment: Why do you *prefer* `sed`. It sucks at such tasks. `sed` is ***very*** good at what it was intended to do, which is:  text Stream EDiting.  What you need is something which can do mathematical work on numbers.  `sed` was not designed for that.   But I'm sure it *can* be done by `sed`, but  that would most likely not be the *preferable* solution... (ps. `sed` rocks! for many jobs, but this isn't one of those)

Comment: @Peter.O I prefer `sed` because this transformation is part of a large number of transformations (like `sed -e 'trasf1' -e 'trasnf2' ... -e 'transfN'), and it seems it'd be easier to continue using this approach. But of course I could just chain the result to some other processor, designed to handle this transformation of long numbers.

Comment: You could use perl e.g. `perl -pe 's/\d{4,}/sprintf "%#x", $&/ge'` which would allow you to maintain the other expressions more-or-less as-is

Comment: @steeldriver:  That's great!  ... make it an answer, otherwise the awsomeness may go unnoticed ... One day, when I grow up, I want to be able to juggle `perl` that well - it makes `awk` look like COBOL :)

Comment: Note that Perl is perfectly capable of doing all the other transformations that you're doing with `sed` too.  So switching to Perl needn't be a big problem, provided you know/learn Perl.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although it's not "with sed" as per your question title, if you switch from sed to perl you could use an equivalent expression such as

```
perl -p -e 's/\b\d{4,}\b/sprintf "%#x", $&/ge'
```

which should allow you to preserve other expressions in your chain more-or-less as is.

Comment: Great. Can this be modified to not transform things like `sd2525`, i.e. things which aren't really numbers? I've tried adding a `([ \t]|^)` before `\d` and `\1` before `sprintf`, but apparently it is treated as a command, not as it'd be in `sed`...

Comment: When you say *...preserve other expressions more-or-less*, are you referring to delimiter spacings? (they seem to be ok)

Comment: I mean to preserve other expressions, only change numbers. Something like this `perl -pe 's/(\s)(\d{4,})(\s)/sprintf "%s%#x%s", $1, $2, $3/ge'`. Are there any caveats in this implementation?

Comment: @Ruslan thanks for the reminder: perhaps simpler, just add word boundary anchors i.e. `\b\d{4,}\b`. I will update my answer.

Comment: @Peter.O I just meant that perl should also be able to handle your other `-e transf` expressions, since it provides a superset of sed's functionality

Comment: Accepting this answer as the simplest, despite not being via `sed`.

Answer (score 7):

The `e` flag of the `s` command of the GNU implementation of `sed` is to evaluate the *content of the pattern space* after the substitution has been applied (successfully), and replace the pattern space with its output, not to evaluate the *substitution*.

Here, for an input like:

```
foo 1234 123
```

You'd need the subsitution to result in the pattern space containing:

```
printf %s 'foo '
printf 0x%x 1234
printf %s ' 123'
```

For the `e` flag to convert that to `foo 0x3d2 123` via the shell command. That's not impossible like with:

```
LC_ALL=C sed -E "
  /[0-9]{4}/!b # optimisation
  s/'/&\\\\&/g
  s/[0-9]{4,}/'\nprintf 0x%x &\nprintf %s '/g
  s/.*/printf %s '&'/e"
```

But that's pretty awkward and means running one shell per matching line of input. Without even using that GNUism, you could as well do:

```
LC_ALL=C sed "
  s/'/&\\\\&/g
  s/[0-9]\{4,\}/'\\
printf 0x%x &\\
printf %s '/g
  s/.*/printf %s '&\\
'/" | sh
```

Which would run *one* `sh`.

Also, evaluating arbitrary data as shell code like that tends to make me nervous. For instance, without the LC_ALL=C above, that would constitute an arbitrary command execution vulnerability. Try for instance on something like the output of:

```
printf '0000\200; echo GOTCHA>&2\n'
```

in a UTF-8 locale.

Here, you'd rather want to use something like `perl`:

```
perl -pe 's/\d{4,}/sprintf "0x%x", $&/ge'
```

`perl`'s `e` flag is more inline with what you expect. It does evalute the subsitution as `perl` code (and is not launching a new perl interpreter every time like with GNU `sed`'s `e`).

Answer (score 5):

`awk` was designed for *exactly* this type of broad-spectrum text manipulation.  Note, there is no need to pipe to any secondary tool(s).

```
awk '{ for( fn=1;fn<=NF;fn++ ){
           fmat=(length($fn)>3)?"0x%x":"%s"
           dlim=(fn==NF?"\n":" ")  
           printf( fmat dlim, $fn )}}' <<<'124 3275 7535'
```

output, as per your sample:

```
124 0xccb 0x1d6f
```

Answer (score 3):

```
echo 124 3275 7535 |
sed 's/.*/[&]p/;s/[0-9]\{4,\}/]P&p[/g;1s/^/16o /' |dc
```

It's not so bad at it. You've just gotta remember what it's for.

There are a couple drawbacks here, though. For example, if there are any square brackets in that input string, the whole thing goes sideways. I have a couple lines to handle that, but I don't know if I wanna dig it up right now.

The other thing is, as written, that will do the hex numbers each followed by a `\n`ewline. Portably it's the only way to go w/ `dc`. W/ GNU `dc` you can replace the `&p` w/ `&n`.

Anyway:

#### output

```
124 CCB
 1D6F
```

With GNU's `n`:

#### output

```
124 CCB 1D6F
```

I guess we could do the `0x` thing, if you want:

```
echo 124 3275 7535|
sed -Ee1i16o -e's/.*/[&]p/;s/[0-9]{4,}/0x]P&n[/g'|dc
```

...which assumes GNU tools all round.

#### output

```
124 0xCCB 0x1D6F
```

Whatever can be said about the other tools in your box, `sed` was designed to turn a stream into something useful. It's not very good w/ numbers, and that's a fact, but it's pretty good at passing them off to those tools which are, such as calculators.

There are other options with GNU `sed` - though none come off as simply, and I expect you'll be hard-pressed to find a solution which does, for that matter. Something like your code in the question:

```
echo 124 3275 7535|
sed -E "h;s/[0-9]{4,}/%#x/g;s/[0-9]+/%d/g
        s/.*/printf '&' \\\\/;G;e"
```

#### output

```
124 0xccb 0x1d6f
```

Comment: Wow! Well done - with sed alone +1. Maybe that should be on the first lines of your answer (as it answered the main preference of his question), I almost missed it at the end...

Comment: @Peter.O - it isn't - it's essentially `system()` - the `dc` way is far preferable. That's a shell per line. It *can* be interesting to have some other process manipulate `sed`'s outfiles in strange ways, but `e` otherwise rarely blips my radar. `dc` is especially good at exactly this kind of thing: try `echo 2o 10000p|dc` or `echo 10000o 10p|dc`. In fact, though, i didn't realize the code in the question was trying to `e` - i thought it was `sed <in |sh` - i guess i just need to look at these things sometimes. I would probably have mentioned it at the outset otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I second what Peter.O said in the comments: here's a `bash` way to do this (it needs a  at the end of each number):

```
echo '124 3275 7535 ' | while read -d ' ' x; do [ ${#x} -ge 4 ] && printf "0x%x " $x || printf "%d " $x; done
```

If your input stream doesn't have a  at the end of the line (as it looks like from your example), than `sed` comes in handy:

```
echo '124 3275 7535' | sed 's/$/ /' | while read -d ' ' x; do [ ${#x} -ge 4 ] && printf "0x%x " $x || printf "%d " $x; done
```